# HttpPostedFileBase could not be found Visual studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

[image]

hi,
i'm working on a asp.net core  mvc with visual studio 2019,
(see attached for the mvc version (3.1.8).
i want to use HttpPostedFileBase, but getting error could not be found,
i've seen a solution suggesting to add using system.Web, and i did, but still getting this error,
Any ideas?

Edit:
Created the html :

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
                <input id="CSVFile" type="file">
            </div>
            <button onclick="Submit()">submit</button>
        </div>
```

and javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Submit() {
            var pdata = new FormData();
            var files = $("#CSVFile").get(0).files;
            window.alert(files.Length);
            pdata.append('CSVFile', files[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: "Index",
                type: "POST",
                data: pdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var input = $("#CSVFile");
                    input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
```

but the controller is not being called (it is defined HttpPost)

```
public ActionResult Index(IFormFile CSVFile)
{
return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.net core 3.1 doesn't contain `HttpPostedFileBase`.If you want to upload files,you can use `IFormFile`,here is [an official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Here is a simple demo to use IFormFile(from view to controller):

view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
            <div>
                <input id="CertImageFile" type="file">
            </div>
            <button onclick="Submit()">submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Submit() {
            var pdata = new FormData();
            var files = $("#CertImageFile").get(0).files;
            pdata.append('CertImageFile', files[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: "Submit",
                type: "POST",
                data: pdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                   var input = $("#CertImageFile");
                   input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
                }
            });
            
        }
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult TestIFormFile()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Submit(IFormFile CertImageFile)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you,
i don't really need to save files in database, i want to upload a csv file just so i can read from it and enter some of the data to the database,
is there any other, more simple way to do it?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: IFormFile is only a type to put file data,it's easy to use.Where do you want to pass the file,view to controller?

Comment: once user press a button in the View , i want to go to the controller , read the data from the file and save data in database. after that, file can be deleted, i dont want to store files in my website.

Comment: I have updated my answer,use ajax to pass data to controller,and after that delete the file in `success: function (data)`

Comment: How is asp-for="CertImageFile" recognized in the View?
can you show me the complete files of the view and controller?
Thank you

Comment: the demo you can use id="CertImageFile",there is no model binding in the demo>I bind the data with $("#CertImageFile") in Submit function.so it's a complete demo,and I have change asp-for to id in my demo

Comment: I edit the post.
added all but action  in controller is not being called

Comment: Is the Index in the same controller,and F12 ,can you see something wrong in Console?

Comment: Added to the URL the controller name before the function and it worked.
Thank you!!! you are awesome :)